# Path to nested column not found in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, xml-parsing, apache-spark-sql

I'm having an issue and I'm not sure if Spark DataFrames are the problem or spark-xml which I'm using to parse an XML file into Spark. I would really appreciate any help.

So, I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <path>
    <to>
      <atag>
        <atag_number>1</atag_number>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>1111</text>
          </again>
        </more>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>2222</text>
          </again>
        </more>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>3333</text>
          </again>
        </more>
      </atag>
      <atag>
        <atag_number>2</atag_number>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>4444</text>
          </again>
        </more>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>5555</text>
          </again>
        </more>
        <more>
          <again>
            <text>6666</text>
          </again>
        </more>
      </atag>
    </to>
  </path>
</root>
```

and I would like to get a table containing `path.to.atag.more.again.text`. I want them to be atomic, so it would need to be exploded to get a row for each `text` value.

If I select e.g. `path.to.atag[0].more.again.text`, I get a list ['1111','2222','3333'].
But if I want all a tags from the file, so if I select `path.to.atag.more.again.text`, I get an error, saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "...\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.selectExpr.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field text in again; line 1 pos 0

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.findField(complexTypeExtractors.scala:85)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExtractValue$.apply(complexTypeExtractors.scala:58)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:253)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:252)

    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)

    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:252)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveChildren(LogicalPlan.scala:148)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$31.apply(Analyzer.scala:604)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$31.apply(Analyzer.scala:604)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:48)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:604)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:600)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:191)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:201)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:205)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)

    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:205)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(QueryPlan.scala:210)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:210)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:600)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:542)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:542)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:479)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)

    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)

    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)

    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:65)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:51)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2603)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:969)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.selectExpr(Dataset.scala:1004)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)

    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)

    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)

    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)

    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)

    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\MyModule.py", line 67, in <module>
    df_output = df.selectExpr('path.to.atag.more.again.text')
  File "...\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 875, in selectExpr
    jdf = self._jdf.selectExpr(self._jseq(expr))
  File "...\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "...\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'No such struct field text in again; line 1 pos 0'
```

Answer (score 2):

You shold explode `atag` also, for example:

```
atags = df.select(explode(df.path.to.atag))
atags.select(explode(atags.col.more.again.text))
```

Above snippet will give you DF with 6 rows - one for every tag

**EDIT:**

If you have xml files with different schema each, using spark Dataframes is not the best solution (Dataframes are designed to work with files with the same schema). If you are looking for specific tags insde files you can try pure RDD API, analyzing files with DOM:

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> def get_tags(xml, tag_name):
...   return [d.childNodes[0].data for d in parseString(xml).getElementsByTagName(tag_name)]
... 
>>> sc.wholeTextFiles('xmls').flatMap(lambda file: get_tags(file[1], "text")).collect()
[u'1111', u'2222', u'3333', u'4444', u'5555', u'6666']
```

Comment: The problem is that I need this to happen dynamically. I don't have fixed columns that I can simply specify in the code. My script takes a set of configurable columns and writes a csv as output. For that I need everything exploded, but I can't know in advance which columns need to explode. With another set of  simpler xml it worked, and I got an array of arrays, which I could explode multiple times in a loop. But somehow in this case it doesn't work, and to explode each part of the path would be too complicated.

Comment: If your XML schema is not static, it will be hard to archieve this in dataframes. You can try this by looping through schema: if field type is array then explode and go deeper, otherwise just select. But you can also try another solution - read XML files by `sc.wholeTextFiles` and use `map` with `xpath` to find all tags with given name, then `flatMap` results and make them dataframe.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what you mean because I'm new at spark and python, and I found spark-xml and dataframes, and thought they were great, until I came across arrays. Basically I need to completely flatten an XML file, so that I can then select columns into a csv, as I wrote here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432974/explode-flatten-all-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: Just adding that for this structure:
<root>
  <tug>
    <x>textX</x>
  </tug>
  <teg>
    <tag>
   <sup>
        <a>textA1</a>
        <a>textA2</a>
        <b>textB1</b>
   </sup>
    </tag>
    <tag>
   <sup>
        <a>textA3</a>
        <b>textB2</b>
   </sup>
    </tag>
  </teg>
</root>

the path teg.tag.sup.a is found, and I get:
`[WrappedArray(textA1, textA2), WrappedArray(textA3)]`
so the two levels of arrays here seem to work.
PS: I don't know how to highlight the code above multiline

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you example of method for loading files with different schema each. It looks for a given tag name inside all files, no matter how deep they are located inside each file.

Comment: Thanks for the example. From what I understand though, your code gets a specific tag and returns the list of its values. Unless I'm missing something, that would not be enough for what I need. I need to extract multiple tags and output them as a table,  so I can't just extract separate lists each for a specific tag. They also need to match the relation on a table,and for a complex schema, the lists would not simply match 1:1.

Comment: Some more clarification: All XML files for one execution are the same structure. It's just that instead of a static structure in the code, the script gets the XML file and the required column list as an input, and returns the data from those columns. The output needs to be a table though because there are multiple columns, not just a list of data from a specific tag. The problem is that I can't access tags inside all items of an array directly, without exploding the array. I explain my attempt here: stackoverflow.com/questions/40432974/explode-flatten-all-columns-in-a-spark-dataframe